# Knockout not disposing of dialog when removing template

Tags: jquery-ui, knockout.js, jquery-ui-dialog

Solution Here: http://jsfiddle.net/lookitstony/24hups0e/6/
Crimson's comment lead me to a solution.

I am having an issue with KO and the Jquery UI dialog. The dialogs are not being destroyed with the template that loaded them.

I was previously storing an instance of the dialog and reusing it over and over without using the binding handler. After reading a few posts about the included binding handler I felt perhaps that was the best way to handle the dialogs. Am I using knockout wrong? Should I stick with the stored reference or does KO have a better way to handle this? If this was an SPA, how would I manage this if I was swapping between pages that may or may not have these dialogs?

You can witness this behaviour by checking out my example here: http://jsfiddle.net/lookitstony/24hups0e/2/

JAVASCRIPT

```
(function () {
    ko.bindingHandlers.dialog = {
        init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
            var options = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor()) || {};
            setTimeout(function () {
                options.close = function () {
                    allBindingsAccessor().dialogVisible(false);
                };

                $(element).dialog(options);
            }, 0);

            //handle disposal (not strictly necessary in this scenario)
            ko.utils.domNodeDisposal.addDisposeCallback(element, function () {
                $(element).dialog("destroy");
            });
        },
        update: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
            var shouldBeOpen = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(allBindingsAccessor().dialogVisible),
                $el = $(element),
                dialog = $el.data("uiDialog") || $el.data("dialog");

            //don't call open/close before initilization
            if (dialog) {
                $el.dialog(shouldBeOpen ? "open" : "close");
            }
        }
    }
})();


$(function () {

    var vm = {
        open: ko.observable(false),
        content: ko.observable('Nothing to see here...'),
        templateOne: ko.observable(true),
        templateTwo: ko.observable(false),

        templateOneHasDialog: ko.observable(true),
        showOne: function(){
            this.templateTwo(false);
            this.templateOne(true);
        },
        showTwo: function(){
            this.templateOne(false);
            this.templateTwo(true);
        },

        diagOpt: {
            autoOpen: false,
            position: "center",
            modal: true,
            draggable: true,
            width: 'auto'
        },
        openDialog: function () {
            if(this.templateOneHasDialog()){            
                this.content('Dialog opened!');
                this.open(open);                
            } else {
                this.content('No Dialog Available');
            }
        }
    }

    ko.applyBindings(vm);
});
```

HTML

```
<div id='ContentContainer'>
Experience Multiple Dialogs
    <ul>
        <li>Click "Open Dialog"</li>
        <li>Move the dialog out of the center and notice only 1 dialog</li>
        <li>Close Dialog</li>
        <li>Now click "One" and "Two" buttons back and forth a few times</li>
        <li>Now click "Open Dialog"</li>
        <li>Move the dialog and observe the multiple dialogs</li>        
    </ul>
    <button data-bind="click:showOne">One</button>
    <button data-bind="click:showTwo">Two</button>

    <!-- ko if: templateOne -->
    <div data-bind="template:{name:'template-one'}"></div>
    <!-- /ko -->
    <!-- ko if: templateTwo -->
    <div data-bind="template:{name:'template-two'}"></div>
    <!-- /ko -->
</div>

<script type="text/html" id="template-one">
    <h3>Template #1</h3>
    <p data-bind="text:content"></p>

    <div><input type= "checkbox" data-bind="checked:templateOneHasDialog" /> Has Dialog </div>

    <button data-bind="click:openDialog">Open Dialog</button>

    <!-- ko if: templateOneHasDialog -->
    <div style="display:none" data-bind="dialog:diagOpt, dialogVisible:open">
        The Amazing Dialog!
     </div>
     <!-- /ko -->

</script>

<script type="text/html" id="template-two">
    Template #2
</script>
```

Comment: The component binding would simplify all of this.

Comment: @CrimsonChris, I wish I could say your comment helped. I have looked into the components but they just look like a fancy layer over the template/viewmodels. Can you elaborate a little more on how this would help or provide an example to clearly demonstrate?

Comment: The component binding can be dynamic. You could make a bunch of dialog components and then pass one of their names to a "dialog layer" that is responsible for displaying dialog components.

Comment: @CrimsonChris, your comment helped a lot. I created a generic dialog div at the page level. Created a mini model on my page module and now pass in the template name and data so i can have a single dialog and reuse it for all dialogs. I placed the template for the dialog content inside the actual dialog tag so it can be dynamically loaded. I am assuming this is kinda what you meant except with components. If you post your comment as the answer with a little more info I will mark as answer otherwise I will just post what I have done. thank you!

Comment: No comment on why the down vote? I provided minimal code sample and my question is very clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using `dialog` inside template the `init` method will be called every time when the template is shown and hence multiple dialogs are appeared in your case. To resolve this place the dialog outside the `template`.

```
<div style="display:none" data-bind="dialog:diagOpt, dialogVisible:open">
    The Amazing Dialog!
 </div>
```

Place this outside the template and now the issue will be resolved.

Updated fiddle: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/madhust/24hups0e/4/)

**Edit:** I went through your code and found that the `ko.utils.domNodeDisposal.addDisposeCallback` has not been triggered in your case. And hence the dialog has not been destroyed on template change which in returns shows multiple dialog.

> But why `ko.utils.domNodeDisposal.addDisposeCallback` has not called?

The `ko.utils.domNodeDisposal.addDisposeCallback` will be triggered when the element(rendered using custom binding) in the template is removed from DOM. But in your case, the dialog element is appended to the `body` instead of `template` and so it was not triggered

**Solution**

The `jquery ui 1.10.0+` have option to specify where the dialog element has to be appended using `appendTo` option we can use that to resolve this.

```
 diagOpt: {
        autoOpen: false,
        position: "center",
        modal: true,
        draggable: true,
        width: 'auto',
        appendTo: "#DesiredDivID"
    },

 <script type="text/html" id="template-one">
<h3>Template #1</h3>
<p data-bind="text:content"></p>

<div><input type= "checkbox" data-bind="checked:templateOneHasDialog" /> Has Dialog </div>

<button data-bind="click:openDialog">Open Dialog</button>

<!-- ko if: templateOneHasDialog -->
<div id="DesiredDivID"></div>
<div id="dlg" data-bind="dialog:diagOpt, dialogVisible:open">
    The Amazing Dialog!
 </div>

     <!-- /ko -->

</script>
```

Now the dialog element will be appended to the `#DesiredDivID` and destroyed on template change.

See the updated fiddle: [Updated one-April-1](http://jsfiddle.net/madhust/24hups0e/7/)

Comment: This did indeed work, how would I ensure that the dialog is with the template though? What if another develop comes behind me and needs to  reuse the page requiring the dialog and does not realize there is a dialog directly related?

Comment: I am also having issues in my real application getting the templates data in the dialog  because of moving it out.

Comment: Thanks for the explination on why the dialog was not going away, It no longer centers right but this answered exactly what I was looking for.